# PHP mysql_query() manually enter date works a PHP variable doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a form that inserts data into a database. One of the fields is `weDate` which is filled in with

```
$weDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Friday'))
```

If I use the following:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT ID as 'DB_ID', 
                         partnumber as 'Part_Number', 
                         pndesc as 'Part Number Description', 
                         name as 'Name', 
                         reason as 'Reason', 
                         comment as 'Comments', 
                         date as 'Date', 
                         time as 'Time', 
                         weDate as 'Weekend Date' 
                    FROM $table 
                    WHERE weDate = '2013-05-03'");
```

I get results back.

When I try:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT ID as 'DB_ID', 
                         partnumber as 'Part_Number', 
                         pndesc as 'Part Number Description', 
                         name as 'Name', 
                         reason as 'Reason', 
                         comment as 'Comments', 
                         date as 'Date', 
                         time as 'Time', 
                         weDate as 'Weekend Date'
                    FROM $table 
                    WHERE weDate = '$weDate2'");
```

I get nothing back. Why?

The PHP variable is:

```
$weDate2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 weeks Friday')
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Which Friday are you referring to? If you run `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Friday'))` you will get `2013-05-10`.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out $weDate2 to see what it is actually outputting?  I'm betting the problem lies within what it is actually outputting versus what you're expecting it to output.

Comment: `$var2 = $var = somefunc();` is invalid syntax, I'm pretty sure. It should just be `$weDate2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Friday')); $weDate = $weDate2;`

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: It is not incorrect syntax. Tony, did you do a simple print of $weDate2?

Comment: Sorry copied the PHP variable incorrectly into this post, I have updated it. @Terry the database has data with weDate 2013-05-03. I did print out weDate2 and get 2013-05-03 on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime("Friday")` returns the upcoming Friday, namely May 10th. This is not the May 3rd you have in the hard-coded query.

Comment: Right..had the incorrect code posted in my post. Been updated.